# React State: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am following along with Wes Bos' *React for Beginners* course, and in the State video, he writes the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddFishForm extends Component {

    nameRef = React.createRef();
    priceRef = React.createRef();
    statusRef = React.createRef();
    descRef = React.createRef();
    imageRef = React.createRef();

    createFish = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const fish = {
            nameRef: this.nameRef.value.value,
            priceRef: parseFloat(this.priceRef.value.value),
            statusRef: this.statusRef.value.value, 
            descRef: this.descRef.value.value,
            imageRef: this.imageRef.value.value,
        }
        console.log(this); //or console.log(fish)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="fish-edit" onSubmit={this.createFish}>
                <input name="name" ref={this.nameRef} type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input name="price" ref={this.priceRef} placeholder="Price"/>
                <select name="status" ref={this.statusRef}>
                    <option value="available">Fresh!</option>
                    <option value="unavailable">Sold Out!</option>
                </select>
                <textarea name="desc" ref={this.descRef} placeholder="Desc"/>
                <input name="image" ref={this.imageRef} type="text" placeholder="Image"/>
                <button type="submit">+ Add Fish</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default AddFishForm;
```

Whenever I try to click the Add Fish button, it gives an error:

```
AddFishForm.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at AddFishForm._this.createFish (AddFishForm.js:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:270)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:561)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:583)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:680)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:688)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:662)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:816)
    at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:824)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:4820)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:18932)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2150)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4899)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:18987)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2169)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4876)
```

There are certain things that I would like to point out in his code. He does not use a constructor (props) function with its associated binding statement, and instead opts for turning createFish into an arrow function. Almost every other question on State I see uses a constructor function. Should I be following suit, or is it okay to use the arrow notation (though it is not standard yet)?

---

Moreover, in the related `StorePicker.js` file, he writes the following code which is supposed to get you from the StorePicker page to the App page via routing. Yet, when I click the Go To Store button in my app, the app only reloads and does not go forth. What should I be doing differently?

Code for `StorePicker.js`:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { getFunName } from '../helpers';

class StorePicker extends React.Component { //OR: ...extends Component (if you import { Component }).
    constructor () {
            super();
            console.log('Create a component!')
            this.goToStore = this.goToStore.bind(this);
    }
    
    myInput = React.createRef();
    goToStore(event) {
        //1. Stop the form from submitting.
            event.preventDefault();
        //2. Get the text from that input. Not going to select using document.querySelector or jQuery here.
        /*IMPORTANT!
            We need to bind ‘this’ to the StorePicker component so that it remains accessible from a member function.
            Either declare a constructor, as shown at the top, or turn goToStore into a function w/ arrow notation.
            goToStore = (event) => {}
        */
            const storeName = this.myInput.value.value;
        //3. Change the page to /store/whatever-they-entered. This uses push state instead of actually moving to a new page.
            this.props.history.push(`/store/${storeName}`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h1>StorePicker</h1>
                <form className="store-selector">
                    <h2>Please enter a store.</h2>
                    <input type="text" 
                        ref={this.myInput}
                        required placeholder="Store name"
                        defaultValue={getFunName()}>
                    </input>
                    <button type="submit">Visit Store »
                    </button>
                </form>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default StorePicker;
```

And for `Router.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import StorePicker from './StorePicker';
import App from './App';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={StorePicker} />
            <Route path="/store/:storeId" component={App} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />  {/*Default catch-all. */}
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue Refs

When accessing refs, you need to access the `current` attribute.

[Accessing Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs)

> When a ref is passed to an element in `render`, a reference to the node
> becomes accessible at the `current` attribute of the ref.

```
ref.current.<property>
```

Code

```
const fish = {
  nameRef: this.nameRef.current.value,
  priceRef: parseFloat(this.priceRef.current.value),
  statusRef: this.statusRef.current.value, 
  descRef: this.descRef.current.value,
  imageRef: this.imageRef.current.value,
}
```

## Question 1

> He does not use a constructor (props) function with its associated
> binding statement, and instead opts for turning createFish into an
> arrow function. Almost every other question on State I see uses a
> constructor function. Should I be following suit, or is it okay to use
> the arrow notation (though it is not standard yet)?

`AddFishForm` has no state and all the class properties that are functions are arrow functions so they don't need to explicitly have `this` bound to them in the constructor. Additionally, you can declare the state class property sans a constructor too.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  state = {...}
  ...
```

## Question 2

> ...code which is supposed to get you from the StorePicker page to the App
> page via routing. Yet, when I click the Go To Store button in my app,
> the app only reloads and does not go forth. What should I be doing
> differently?

The problem here is the button has `type="submit"` and is within a form, which when clicked will make the form take default actions, i.e. try to submit the form and reload the page. The `this.goToStore` also doesn't appear to be used at all.

```
<form className="store-selector">
  <h2>Please enter a store.</h2>
  <input type="text" 
    ref={this.myInput}
    required
    placeholder="Store name"
    defaultValue={getFunName()}
  />
  <button type="submit"> // <-- causes form to submit and take default actions
    Visit Store »
  </button>
</form>
```

### Solution

1. Change the button type to `type="button"` and add an `onClick` handler, `onClick={this.goToStore}`
2. Attach `this.goToStore` to the form's `onSubmit` handler `<form onSubmit={this.goToStore}>`

I'm going to guess `goToStore` was intended to be used by the form.

```
<form
  className="store-selector"
  onSubmit={this.goToStore}
>
  <h2>Please enter a store.</h2>
  <input type="text" 
    ref={this.myInput}
    required
    placeholder="Store name"
    defaultValue={getFunName()}
  />
  <button type="submit">
    Visit Store »
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: How about the second part of the question, routing from the StorePicker to the main app? Even after I write const storeName = this.myInput.current.value.value; the Visit Store button only reloads the current page and does not proceed, despite the presence of preventDefault().

Comment: @ProximanovaMetropolis Ah, generally SO posts should be limited to a single issue/question, but I'll take a look.

Comment: @ProximanovaMetropolis Hopefully addressed questions/concerns.